# .htaccess rewrite rule to add html at the end of a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule shop/hats/([0-9]+)/ shop/item.php?id=$1
```

This will rewrite a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/item.php?id=3
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/hats/2/
```

My question is, how do I modify this to rewrite the URL to:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/hats/2.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` just represents the matched pattern in parentheses – if you had additional sets you could use `$2`, `$3`, etc. So `$1.html` instead of `$1` should do the trick.

Edit: if your example URLs are correct, your rule is quite wrong. Try something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/shop/item.php /shop/hats/%1.html? [R=301]
```

You need to use RewriteCond to match against the query string, and `%1` instead of `$1` to reference that match.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a minor tweak in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/hats/([0-9]+)\.html$ shop/item.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```